# magento api/cron product disables all api products

Tags: api, magento, cron

I have an unusual problem. After cron updates product database via API, all API products are disabled. Every morning I have to go in to catalogue, select all and change status into enabled.

This is not ideal because then I have to go and disable some old products that are still there. So far after each API update via cron products were enabled.

I have no clue what might have cause it or where to change it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more info like what version of cron, magento, OS and other tools you use and configuration files? There's very little to go on to help you at the moment.

Comment: Magento: 1.9.3.8
Cron I was unable to identify system wouldn't let me check it's logs etc although I was root
Centos-elease-6.7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 
Which configuration files should I post? To be honest normally a friend helps me with this website but he is on holiday till Monday. I was trying to do something with it myself that's why I asked but I think it is still too deep water for me, if you have any advice I will be grateful but so far I wasn't able to check cron logs trying for 2 days :(